# How to copy .oci image to docker registry

Tags: buildpack

getting below error while trying to copy **run_img.oci** image to registry

**Error**

```
FATA[0000] Error loading trust policy: open /etc/containers/policy.json: no such file or directory
```

created .oci images from the **stack.toml**, as per the [document](https://paketo.io/docs/howto/create-custom-stack/#prerequisites)

**executed the below command**-

```
skopeo copy oci-archive:/home/ubuntu/builder_custom/stack docker-daemon:deepak0705/deepakdocker:stack_run
```

getting thebelow error

```
FATA[0000] Error loading trust policy: open /etc/containers/policy.json: no such file or directory
```

tried creating the policy.json file in the mentioned path **/etc/containers/policy.json**,
with below configuration

```
{
    "default" : {
    "type": "accept"
     }
}
```

now am getting below error

```
FATA[0000] Error loading trust policy: invalid policy in "/etc/containers/policy.json": json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []json.RawMessage
```